# W/Finsky: [528] com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.cb.a(171): Exception reading file:///storage/sdcard1/Android/app-release.apk

Tags: android, apk

i'm developping an android app ! I extract the apk and i tried to install it on two device but the following message appears " Application is not installed" 
when I took a look on my logcat i found this exception ! I don't know if this is the real problem or there's another! and I don't know how to resolve it 
thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forget select both signature versions when building my signed apk.[image]

Comment: In my case it was a problem of missed permission ( permession of media)